# \n problem when splitting and getting different outputs

Tags: python

```
def func():
    a="2.60\n11.00\n35.00\n4.25\n4.00\n7.00\n22.00\n12.00\n5.25"
    a=a.split("\n")
    print(a)
    b=input("sdasd?")
    #I enter 2.60\n11.00\n35.00\n4.25\n4.00\n7.00\n22.00\n12.00\n5.25 then i get differen outputs.

    b=b.split("\n")
    print(b)

func()
```

I could not tell why there is a difference between these.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is that `input` is escaping special characters as `\\` and therefor `\\n` is not equal to `\n`.

This is why you see `['2.60\\n11.00\\n35.00\\n4.25\\n4.00\\n7.00\\n22.00\\n12.00\\n5.25']` as the result. Changing your code as follows solves the problem:

```py
b=b.split("\\n")
```

Comment: So,what should i do in order to get same output when inputting?How can i ensure that input does not escape these special string characters?

Answer (score 0):

`input('prompt')` reads user input until it reads a newline.  You can't enter `2.68<Enter>11.00<Enter> ...` in a single input.  I think you are actually typing in the `\n` between the numbers.

This is how that gets read:

`2.60` -> `2.60`

`\`    -> a `backslash`, ASCII decimal 92

`n` -> `n`, ASCII Decimal 110

So you have one string, consisting of digits separated by a backslash and an n.

Python represents this string as `2.60\\n11.00...`, telling you that the `\` is an actual backslash, not a modifier to be applied to `n`.  `Split` splits nothing, because the string does not contain any actual newline character (ASCII Decimal 10 on a Unix System).